# Video Window does not respond, windowed mode, DirectShow

Tags: c++, windows, com, directshow

I wanted to use Vmr 9 instead of default Vmr 7, so I created it with CoCreateInstance and added to the graph with AddFilter method. Next, I build graph with RenderFile method. Now renderer is connected, so I query for IVideoWindow interface and call put_Owner method with window handle created in child thread. When Run method is called, video is displayed in the window, but window doesn't handle messages, so you can't move it or resize. Windowless mode works fine. Why window behaves this way?

```
#include <dshow.h>

#include <D3D9.h>
#include <Vmr9.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Strmiids.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3d9.lib")

#define WM_GRAPHNOTIFY  WM_APP + 1

DWORD HandleGraphEvent(IMediaEventEx* media_event)
{
    long EvCode;
    LONG_PTR param1, param2;
    while (media_event->GetEvent(&EvCode, &param1, &param2, 0) == S_OK)
    {
        media_event->FreeEventParams(EvCode, param1, param2);
        switch (EvCode)
        {
        case EC_COMPLETE:
            printf("All data is rendered\n");
            return 0;
        case EC_USERABORT:
            printf("User has closed the window\n");
            return 0;
        case EC_ERRORABORT:
            printf("Error occured\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

struct WindowThreadParam
{
    HANDLE event;
    HWND window;

    IMediaEventEx* media_event;
};

LRESULT WINAPI WindowProcedure(HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    WindowThreadParam* param = (WindowThreadParam*)lp;

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_GRAPHNOTIFY:
        HandleGraphEvent(param->media_event);
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI WindowThread(WindowThreadParam* param)
{
    LPCWSTR myclass = TEXT("myclass");

    WNDCLASSEX wndclass =
    { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
    0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION),
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),
    0, myclass, LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION) };

    HWND window = NULL;

    if (RegisterClassEx(&wndclass))
    {
        window = CreateWindowEx(0, myclass, TEXT("title"),
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);

        if (window)
        {
            ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

            param->window = window;
            SetEvent(param->event);

            MSG msg;
            while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else SetEvent(param->event);

        UnregisterClass(myclass, GetModuleHandle(0));
    }
    else SetEvent(param->event);

    return 0;
}

void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE event_handle;
    event_handle = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);       // auto, unsignaled

    WindowThreadParam param;
    ZeroMemory(&param, sizeof(param));
    param.event = event_handle;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)WindowThread, &param, 0, NULL);

    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEventEx   *pEvent = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return;
    }

    IGraphBuilder* graph_builder;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&graph_builder);

    IBaseFilter* Vrm;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&Vrm);
    hr = graph_builder->AddFilter(Vrm, L"Video Mixing Renderer");

    hr = graph_builder->RenderFile(L"anim.avi", NULL);

    hr = graph_builder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = graph_builder->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEventEx, (void **)&pEvent);

    IVideoWindow* VideoWindow;
    RECT window_client_area;

    WaitForSingleObject(param.event, INFINITE);
    if (param.window)
    {
        // set window
        hr = graph_builder->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow, (void**)&VideoWindow);
        hr = VideoWindow->put_Owner((OAHWND)param.window);
        hr = VideoWindow->put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
        // set video position
        GetClientRect(param.window, &window_client_area);
        hr = VideoWindow->SetWindowPosition(0, 0, window_client_area.right, window_client_area.bottom);

        param.media_event = pEvent;
        hr = pEvent->SetNotifyWindow((OAHWND)param.window, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, (LONG_PTR)&param);
    }

    hr = pControl->Run();

    // allow child thread to run
    getchar();

    pControl->Release();
    pEvent->Release();
    graph_builder->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread sleeps in `getchar();` when it is supposed to implement message pump and deliver window messages, both as COM requirement and for the helper window VMR creates in the main thread.

Your background thread is irrelevant here since your controlling DirectShow activity takes place in `_tmain`.

Comment: So, I assume that SetNotifyWindow method is irrelevant in windowed mode and you are supposed to get messages manually with GetMessage and deliver them to your window. As I stated background thread works fine in windowless mode when main thread sleeps.

Comment: `SetNotifyWindow` is fine. Not fine is that you create COM STA, then you have windows there attached to this thread, and you sleep not dispatching messages.

Comment: Ok, it works in main thread. So, I assume that windowed mode is not designed for multiple threads (because windowless mode works fine).

Comment: Windowed mode works fine with multiple threads, provided that you comply with threading rules.

Comment: Also, with notify window graph does not dispatch EC_USERABORT message, when you get it manually with GetEvent there is no problem though.